No matching export in "node_modules/.pnpm/@ledgerhq+errors@6.16.4/ for import "TransportRaceCondition"
Getting this error when initializing a new React App with the Anza wallet Adapter
Error
✘ [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/.pnpm/@ledgerhq+errors@6.16.4/node_modules/@ledgerhq/errors/lib-es/index.js" for import "TransportRaceCondition"

    node_modules/.pnpm/@ledgerhq+hw-transport@6.27.1/node_modules/@ledgerhq/hw-transport/lib-es/Transport.js:74:9:
      74 │ import { TransportRaceCondition, TransportError, StatusCodes, getAltStatusMessage, TransportStatusError, } from "@ledgerhq/errors";
         ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

18:01:31 [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/.pnpm/@ledgerhq+hw-transport@6.27.1/node_modules/@ledgerhq/hw-transport/lib-es/Transport.js:74:9: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/.pnpm/@ledgerhq+errors@6.16.4/node_modules/@ledgerhq/errors/lib-es/index.js" for import "TransportRaceCondition"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/home/jimii/Documents/web3/solana/adapter-test/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.20.2/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1651:15)
    at /home/jimii/Documents/web3/solana/adapter-test/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.20.2/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1059:25
    at /home/jimii/Documents/web3/solana/adapter-test/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.20.2/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1527:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Steps to Reproducing

Initialialize a new vite + pnpm project selecting Typscript + SWC compiler

Install dependencies


pnpm install --save \                                                                         
    @solana/wallet-adapter-base \
    @solana/wallet-adapter-react \
    @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui \
    @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets \
    @solana/web3.js \
    react


start the development server

 pnpm dev

Environment
OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64
GitHub repo https://github.com/687c/adapter-test
